# How to add a logo and Text in toolbar or Navigation Bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to add logo and text this way:

Logo on the Leftside and Text Inside Toolbar or Navigation Bar:

Logo MyCompany

I tried below code:

From P1 to MainMenuPage

--in  P1 :

use Approach 1:

```
   NavigationPage NP = new NavigationPage(new MainMenuPage())
    {
           Title = "Company Name",
           Icon = "itemIcon1",
           BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
           BarTextColor = Color.DarkGray
     };

    App.Current.MainPage = NP;
```

this approach 
- it will show the Navigational Bar BUT no icon and no text

--- In P1 using Approach 2 :

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainMenuPage());
```

- this approach , it Dont show Navigation Bar at all!

even I put this in MainMenuPage. The ToolBar wont show too!

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems> 
  <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="Microsoft.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" /> 
  <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="Xamarin.png" Text="Item 2" Priority="1" /> 
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

below is the MainMenuPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MainMenuPage"> 
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <Label Text = "welcome" FontSize="24"/>
      <Label Text = "Show Company Logo"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>    
</ContentPage>
```

Would like to have help on this from you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two to do this.

**1st solution** :
You don't show the navigation bar but you create it manually in Xamarin.Forms. You can still be in a navigation page but you add this in the constructor of your content page:

```
NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, true);
```

Then in your page you build your own navigation bar manually.

**2nd solution**:
You do it with a custom renderer of your content page (and not the renderer of the navigation page).

For ios, you can have something like:

```
public class ContentPageSubtitleRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    //Call this method when you need it
    // It can be in OnElementChanged and/or when a property is updated
    private void SetBar()
    {
            var navigationItem = NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;

            navigationItem.TitleView = myUIView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to have both Droid & iOS to show the same thing.  For iOS , can you show me step by step how to implement the custom renderer? Any simple sample for me to learn. Thanks